# could not get php session variables to other page even I use session_start() at top

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

I have been stuck to get session data on second page, following are sample code for both pages, but on second page I can't get any value in session

```
   for a.php
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["captchacode"] = 123456;
    ?>

    for b.php
    <?php
    session_start(); 

    echo "<pre>"; 

    print_r($_SESSION);

    var_dump($_SESSION);
    die;
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any error?? Did you try to echo $_SESSION["captchacode"]

Comment: No, I got blank value

Comment: Try removing die method and just echo the session with variable captcha

Comment: No, Its not working...well I am sure its not syntaxial mistake, its some thing different may be some server related...but I don't know that exactly